# How to connect Kakfa Consumer from different server using Python

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

I am not able to receive any data from Kafka server to my consumer server.

Kafka Server is hosted in 192.168.1.1 and consumer is hosted in 192.168.1.2
Using **kafka-python** lib.

**Below is my example**

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer('test', bootstrap_servers=['192.168.1.1:9092'],
                     auto_offset_reset='earliest', enable_auto_commit=True,
                     auto_commit_interval_ms=1000)
for message in consumer:
    print(message);
```

If I will *add wrong port number or IP address its throws exception* and which is good sign its connected successfully but when Producer send data it won't be work in **192.168.1.2** this IP address but if I am trying same in **192.168.1.1** this IP address working fine.

Do I need to change any configuration, Please guid me I am new in Kafka.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your server (broker) to have the correct `advertised.listener`.

Have a read of [this blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-06-11&utm_term=rmoff-devx), and try out [this Python code](https://github.com/rmoff/kafka-listeners/blob/master/python/python_kafka_test_client.py) here to understand what's going on with your broker and client.

Comment: Yes changed **advertised.listner** ip address but still having below connection msg

`kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable`